# HTML application checking for updates

Tags: html, iframe

I created a HTML application and I want it to look to see if it's the latest version and then if it is not then show a link.

I'm a beginner to javaScript so if you could tell me how to fix this code that would be great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisVersion = 1.5

function checkForUpdate() {
    document.getElementById("version").value;
    if (value == > "thisVersion")
        updateMessage.style.display = 'block'
    else
        updateMessage.style.display = 'none'
}
</script>

<iframe src="my page where i say the latest version" scrolling="no" width="0" height="0" style="display:none"></iframe>

<table id="updateMessage" style="display:none">
There is a new version avalabal please download the new verion
<input type="button" value="here" src="update page">
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: the latest version of what? isn't the webpage already the latest, if the user just opens it in the browser? what is it exactly that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: This is not online it is a downloadable HTML file. I want there to be a message displayed if there is a newer version of the HTML file. So I was wondering how to do this. I was planning on putting a file on my server saying the newest version and then I wanted the downloaded HTML file to look at the server and compare it to it's version and if it's version was smaller then the latest version display a message.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: if the downloaded HTML file has "to look at the server and compare it to it's version", might as well leave the the HTML file on the server and have the users access it online. Unless if you are making Adobe AIR app or HTML Help file (CHM) or something, this whole "get the latest HTML to download" business seems weird to me. HTML is not for download.

Comment: Yeah...as Lukman has stated, this really is a thing in which you are trying to make something harder than it should be.  In order for the user to properly utilize this file, they will need an internet connection, so why not just have it hosted on a server instead?  From there, if you insist on something of the sort, have the javascript check a local file periodically and inform the user that something has updated when you update the file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be possible for a HTML page on the user's hard drive to automatically check for and/or download a new version with Javascript. For security reasons, Javascript cannot access iframes from different domains, and AJAX won't work for the same reason. Internet Explorer always displays a warning about Javascript too, which is annoying for users.

One solution is to just keep the page hosted online, since you're going to be checking online anyway.

An alternative is for the downloaded HTML page to display a hosted script, passing its current version in the URL. So if the file the user downloads is version 2, the iframe  would look like this:

```
<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/checkupdate.php?current=2"></iframe>
```

Then the `checkupdates.php` script in the iframe would check the value of 'current' passed into it. If your current version is 2, it could output "You are using the latest version". But if your current version is 3, it could display "There is a newer version of this file - click here to download it".

Then the version 3 of the page would have this iframe instead:

```
<iframe src="http://yoursite.com/checkupdate.php?current=3"></iframe>
```

Note: you can style the iframe to remove the borders/scrollbars if you want it to look more "inline".

Comment: Isn't it possible to check for updates by retrieving a web page's [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)? The ETag should change whenever the page is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an iframe that contains a web page with the "latest version" info, you could have a script tag that points to a js on your web server that has the newest version set in a variable:

Content of version.js on your web server:

```
var latestVersion = 1.5;
```

html in the downloaded page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite.com/version.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisVersion = 1.4;
function checkForUpdate() {

    if (thisVersion < latestVersion )
        updateMessage.style.display = 'block';
    else
        updateMessage.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```